# How tell the local time of a web visitor?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm building a blog engine in CakePHP and I would like to show the current visitor articles relative to their local time of day.

For visitors where it's currently morning, then I'll show articles related to starting your day and news items that happened overnight.

For visitors where it's currently evening, then I'll show articles that recap the highlights of major events during the day.

The only possible solution I can think of is to send their current timezone via Javascript to the server, but this can only happen after the web page has loaded. How can I did this at the time the CakePHP application renders the pagination view for index action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure about php, However this will work in all language.
You better store difference in GMT for user using

```
 i copied syntax from internet
    var d = new Date()
    var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

now at very first page, run this code on page load and store value of n in DB using ajax or whatever.SO whenever your user login you get the time diff till he/she logout.Use that DB value (store in session for better use) to further process.

Further create function like

```
addGMTDiff()
{
  // fetch stored value for difference and return
}
```

call this function after every sql query that fetched UTC time.